# Using VB.net DataGrid view to interact with SQL DB. Update/Delete/Add

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

**Setup Information**

I have "Form1" with a DataGrid View ("DataGridView1") which populates with Data from an SQL server table.
It's a simple table, with about 10 records.

The table used is "jamesTestVBlol"
The dataset is named "DataSetJames.xsd"
I believe the table adaptor is called "JamesTestVBlolTableAdaptor"

**Question**

Is there a way, I can update a record and send these changes back to the server.

e.g. Column 1, record 1 I would like to change to "TEST" and update this table on the server.

The only code I have is:

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DataSetJames.jamesTestVBlol' table.' You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.JamesTestVBlolTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSetJames.jamesTestVBlol)
  End Sub 

End Class
```

Could anyone help me with where I need to look?
I've tried to read several online tutorials, but generally they are above my head.

Thanks,
James.